# How can I override a package source in Nix?

Tags: nix

So I want to replace `pkgs.picom` in my home-manager config with a newer fork. How can I do that?

I have a feeling it's something like:

```
let newPicom = pkgs.picom.override.src.url = "https://github.com/ibhagwan/picom";  
in 
services.picom.package = newPicom;
```

But knowing Nix is probably actually some really long incantation with `self: super:` and so on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`nixos.wiki` [has an example](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Overlays#Overriding_a_version) of overriding the source of a package.

You do need to provide a reproducible source. A github repo url is mutable, so you need to specify the revision.

```
{ pkgs, ... }:
let newPicom = pkgs.picom.overrideAttrs (old: {
      version = "git"; # usually harmless to omit
      src = /* put your source here; typically a local path or
               a fixed-output derivation produced by
               `fetchFromGitHub`.
               builtins.fetchGit is also an option. Doesn't run
               in parallel but does fetch private sources. */;
    });
in {
  services.picom.package = newPicom; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Overlays

```
let
  picom_overlay = (self: super: {
    picom = super.picom.overrideAttrs (prev: {
      version = "git";
      src = pkgs.fetchFromGitHub {
        owner = "yshui";
        repo = "picom";
        rev = "31e58712ec11b198340ae217d33a73d8ac73b7fe";
        sha256 = pkgs.lib.fakeSha256;
      };
    });
  });
in
  nixpkgs.overlays = [ picom_overlay ];
```

Of course, `sha256` should be replaced with the relevant hash shown in the output error after building -- in this case:

```
sha256 = "sha256-VBnIzisg/7Xetd/AWVHlnaWXlxX+wqeYTpstO6+T5cE=";
```

---

#### picom-next

Note that there is also a [`picom-next`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/applications/window-managers/picom/picom-next.nix) package so one can alternatively do:

```
let
  picom_overlay = (self: super: {
    picom = super.picom.overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: rec {
      inherit (super.picom-next) pname version src;
    });
  });
in
  nixpkgs.overlays = [ picom_overlay ];
```

Or more simply with @RobertHensing's suggestion:

```
services.picom.package = pkgs.picom-next;
```

Comment: For posterity (using overlays instead of the `newPicom` answer is practical to make sure the same overridden package is used everywhere): replace `super.` with `self.` in the above overlay function, otherwise you get infinite recursion. (You must be *overriding* the *previous* attribute (maybe better call it `prev` instead of `self`, and to avoid collision the `prev:` (which is unused here) by `_:`).